# Wireguard-ui: `Bad PATH_INFO : /login`

Tags: vpn, scripting, installation, wireguard, webmin

I've successfully installed Wireguard + [UI](https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui) to a Debian11 VPS with [this AIO script](https://gitlab.com/snax44/wireguard-ui-setup/-/blob/master/install.sh).

But if I open the `http://localhost:5000` via Webmin tunneling, I get this error:

`Bad PATH_INFO : /login`

- How do I fix this?

### Edit2:

The problem is only occurring, if I try to reach the UI through Webmin tunneling.
Using the recommended:
`ssh -L 5000:localhost:5000 root@mydomain.net -p 22` binding works.
*(Except I need to type the root password every time to connect.)*